# Run native tests without JVM tests in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, native-maven-plugin, spring-boot-3

Spring 6/Spring Boot 3 allows to [run tests using GraalVM's `native-image` with `mvn -Pnative test`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-RC2/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.testing.with-native-build-tools.maven).

This uses the [`native-maven-plugin`](https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html). This plugin [respects both `-DskipTests` and `-Dmaven.test.skip` and there is also a flag `-DskipNativeTests` to skip native tests only](https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html#testing-support-disabling).

Is there a way to skip "normal" tests (using the surefire plugin) but still preprocess and run native tests?

Comment: can't you do it with `mvn -Pnative -DskipTests `

Comment: @muhammedozbilici That also skips native tests (just like `-Dmaven.test.skip`). As I mentioned in the question, `native-maven-plugin` respects `-DskipTests`, `-Dmaven.test.skip` and `-DskipNativeTests`.